# Is there such a thing as active-panel tracking with i3?

Tags: i3-wm

By this I mean, I generally setup my windows or panels (bottom numbers ie. alt+1 - 2 - 3... etc) to correspond with clients I'm working with. I don't have many right now just two but it would be cool if I could bind a time tracking event for which panel I was active in.

Not sure if I can attach an "event listener" so to speak to an active panel when you switch to it by mouse-click or alt+#

Any thoughts? What language would I use to accomplish this?

Comment: *i3* has an [IPC interface](http://i3wm.org/docs/ipc.html), which - among other things - supports "workspace events". These are sent every time the workspace changes, regardless of *how* the change was effected. This is of course not a ready-to-use solution, but libraries exist for many programming languages. So it should not be to hard to write a small program that notes down time and workspace name everytime it changes.

Comment: @Adaephon cool man thanks. I will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the command line tool `xev`? It basically outputs all sort of X events done within a window(typing, button up, button down, dragging, moving cursors etc.) Hope this helps.